# How to delete SQLite local file after opened?

Tags: php, pdo

I have this:

```
$sqlPdo = new \PDO('sqlite:mySqlite.file');
$q = $sqlPdo->query('SELECT * FROM z');
$sqlPdo = null;
unlink('mySqlite.file');
```

unfortunatly the unlink fails, I cant delete this file.

Comment: Probably the file is locked, since you never close it. Assigning a `null` value to the variable only overwrites the object. http://php.net/manual/en/sqlite3.close.php

Comment: then how to close it?

Comment: Doesn't the link I posted along my comment tell you exactly that?

Comment: @arkascha the PDO object live until the object is destroyed and setting it to null is enough.

Comment: Which user and permissions do your file have after using it?

Comment: @Stony Windows, root